# Cocoapods doesn't see a project added to Xcode framework as viable target

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, xcode7

I'm trying to integrate a new project into an Xcode workspace with dependencies handled by Cocoapods. I added the Backend project (builds fine on itself, returns a framework as a product) to the workspace and added a separate target in the Podfile:

```
target 'Backend' do
(Pod list here)
end
```

Yet when trying to run `pod install`, I get `[!] Unable to find a target named 'Backend'`.

Using Xcode 7.2, Cocoapods 0.39.0

Comment: are you sure target name is 'Backend' ? It can be different from project name

Comment: Positive - both project and product names are 'Backend': [link](http://imgur.com/V6BbojU)

Comment: show the content of podfile

Comment: [Here it is, redacted app/company name, all other targets receive their dependencies just fine](http://imgur.com/DZYLQNN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CocoaPods doesn't support integrating with frameworks, see https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3440

Comment: That explains. Back to Carthage then, I suppose. Thanks!